# Apache Tomcat reject post request for more than 19KB and return 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, server

spring boot application deployed on apache tomcat 9 reject post request larger than 19kb.

the controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/book")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookController {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookController.class);
    
    private final BookServices bookServices;
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")  @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void addBook(@Valid @RequestBody BookModel bookModel) throws SanprException {
        try {
            logger.info("success...");
            bookServices.addBook(bookModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Failed...");
            throw new SanprException(message.toString(), e, Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

the bookModel class,

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookModel {    
        @Id
        private long id;
        private String title;
        private boolean isPublish;
        private boolean isDuplicated;
        private MediaModel background;
        private String pdfFile;
        private String description;
        private List<TableContentsModel> tableContents;
        private GlobalReferentialModel level;
        private GlobalReferentialModel type;

}
```

here my server.xml configuration for apache tomcat,

```
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           address="0.0.0.0"
           redirectPort="8443"
           maxPostSize="-1"
           useIPVHosts="true" />
```

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
    port="8443" connectionTimeout="20000" maxSwallowSize = "-1" maxHttpHeaderSize="819200" 
    keystoreFile="....keystore" keystorePass="****"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
    secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" compression="on" SSSLVerifyClient="none" />
```

and here scrrenshots on postman testing : 
working : https://ibb.co/0K679Hf 
not working : https://ibb.co/4JG2WSR

Comment: so, you "got _a problem_". Which is it? Please read [ask], edit your question with a [mcve] (e.g. show code, describe expected vs observed behavior)

Comment: 404 means "not found" so wherever you're posting to does not exist.

Comment: @Paul not really as i know tomcat reject request with 404 when it has big size then default , otherwise it was working fine with the same post request before deployment on tomcat , tested in postman

Comment: @Asher: can you post the code of the controller method? You encode your `POST`s using the older `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which behaves badly when you go over `maxPostSize`. BTW: it is `404 Not Found` or `400 Bad Request`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz it is a bad request .
and here the controller 
https://ibb.co/fFPcGKD

Comment: A validation error causes a `400 Bad Request` response. That is probably the problem, not the size of the request.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz have you seen the screenshots token from postman ? i have tested with the same object the only difference is one larger by 440KB than the other which is 11KB , and i am pretty sure the problem not in the request object body but its big size

Comment: Can you add `BookModel` to the question? The parameter is annotated with `@Valid` and the class might have some Java Validation constraints.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz okay i added the bookModel class

Comment: I have tested your controller (with `String` instead of `BookModel`) with arbitrarily large files. Neither Tomcat nor Spring generate a `400` response. Hence you should look into your hierarchy of model classes for the one that can generate the error. `BookModel` itself is Ok, but its elements might cause a validation problem.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz the same object i was testing before deployment and it works , but after deployment on tomcat it shows 404 bad request

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz i tried to to post the object for test here but its big than allowed character , i dont know how to